# how to convert z3 expression to infix expression?

Tags: z3

I want to translate boolExpression in Z3 into infix representation. For example, there is a z3 expression (>= t 3), I want to get the infix string "t>=3", is any existing Z3 api to implement it in C# ?

Answer (score 1):

No, the official API does not have support for displaying expressions in infix notation. This functionality can be implemented on top of the API for traversing expressions. The Z3 Python API implements an infix printer. Actually, it implements two: one for Python-like syntax, and one for HTML math-like syntax. The source code of these printers is included in the Z3 distribution. The code is written in python, but can be easily converted into any programming language. The code is located at `python\z3printer.py`.