# Putting equality constraint in z3

Tags: constraints, equality, z3

I am using z3's python API to solve see if a set of constraint is satisfiable or not.
I have the conditions as string and I want to directly pass them to z3 whenever possible, just to save processing time of transcoding it.
If the constraint is an assignment like a = b what is the best way to enter it.
I want something like

```
    str1 = "a = b"
    a = BitVec('a', 3)
    b = BitVec('b', 3)
    s = Solver()
    s.push()
    s.add(str1)
```

This program gives error as "True, False or Z3 Boolean expression expected"
Please let me know the best way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass Z3 expressions to the majority of the API functions (like `Solver.add(expr)`), not strings.  For your example (z3py link: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/iu0 ):

```
str1 = "a = b"
a = BitVec('a', 3)
b = BitVec('b', 3)
constraint1 = a == b # sets constraint1 to be the z3 expression a == b
s = Solver()
s.push()
# s.add(str1) # error: 'True, False or Z3 Boolean expression expected'
s.add(constraint1)
print constraint1
```

If you want to pass strings encoded in infix notation (like "a = b"), you should be able to use Python's `eval`, although this may not work with full generality, so you may have to write a parser, and you cannot use `eval` on rise4fun due to the sanitizer:

```
constraint2 = eval(str1)
```

Here's some more details on using `eval`: [z3python: converting string to expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540306/z3python-converting-string-to-expression)

If you have strings encoded in the SMT-LIB standard (which uses prefix notation, e.g., "(= a b)"), you can use the `parse_smt2_string` API function.  Here's an example continuing from the above:

```
cstr1 = "(assert (= a b))"
ds = { 'a' : a, 'b' : b }
constraint3 = parse_smt2_string(cstr1, decls=ds)
print constraint3
prove(constraint1 == constraint3)
```

Here's the API documentation for `parse_smt2_string`: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/z3.html#-parse_smt2_string

See also this related question and answer on using infix for output of Z3 expressions: [how to convert z3 expression to infix expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612862/how-to-convert-z3-expression-to-infix-expression)